# Visual Studio 2017 Community custom T4 code templates for MVC Core

Tags: ide, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, t4

I am working on a C# netcore2.0 project that would greatly benefit from having my own custom T4 code generation templates for views. I have made a folder in the project root called "CodeTemplates" and copied the MvcView folder from "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates**" to it but my project does not seem to target this newly created folder when using the view scaffolding tools.

I then tried to modify the templates stored in the C:\Program Files (x86).... directory and my VS IDE didn't see these changes either? Am I looking in the wrong place for T4 MVC templates for **VS 2017 Community 15.3.5**? Also, regardless of the correct path, I was under the impression making a sepcificly named "CodeTemplates" folder in the root would override other templates when scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.Net Core it appears code templates no longer come from Program Files. Instead I found the templates were sourcing from C:\Users{username}.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc\2.0.0\Templates

If I copy this Templates folder into the root of my ASP.Net Core project and edit them, the scaffolding wizard will use these edited versions stored in the project.